# Structuring a database for recording large amounts of dynamic data for users

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

I am making a site which allows users to sign up and record their daily activities in a table. Their activities will be stored in a MySQL database, and will be displayed using jQuery/PHP.

Here is an example picture of the type of data being stored[image]

The problem is, I have no idea how to properly store this type of information.

I was originally going to create a table for each user called `$userid . "_activies"` or something along those lines, with the columns `id, user_id, type, location, duration, date`. Then to read the data, I would simply check for what date they want and load all of the activities that match that date. This works fine, but I can't figure out how to update existing entries properly.

For example: In the picture above, if you wanted to change the duration of the "Kitchen" row, how would you go about detecting if it already exists in the database? You can't simply check for a row containing 'cleaning' and 'kitchen' on 11/18/2012 then overwrite it, because Kitchen could appear multiple times in the cleaning section (say they cleaned the Kitchen a second time after going to the Bathroom).

I originally thought about making each `<tr>` have an id equal to the `id` field for the data that it loaded, then when it comes time to save the data, check if the row `id` already exists and overwrite it. This seems like a poor workaround for my issue.

I'd like to be able to just completely clear the original data for the entire day and rewrite it with whatever the table contains when they hit save. Would it be reasonable to just delete every row in the table that matches the date of the table, then write new information? Or is there a better way to store this information. For example, should I create a new table for each day for each user? That seems like a lot of tables...

I'm stumped, can anyone share any ideas on ways to set up the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a big believer in keeping your data in logical chunks.  Never be afraid of using more tables if it means keeping everything logical.  Based just on what you said I would have at least the following tables:

User ( user_id, user_name, password, email, ...)
Location( location_id, location_Name, ...)
Durations ( duration_id, duration_length(increment in 5, 10 or 15 minutes chunks from what would be the smallest duration to what would be the largest))
Activity( activity_id, activity_name, activity_description, activity_user(user_id), activity_date, activity_location(location_id), activity_duration(duration_id)...)

Again, that is based on the elements described in your question.  This way, everything would be stored in Activity, and you would obviously want to index activity_user.  You would simply add activities into Activity as they are entered, and display them based on activity_user and activity_date.  Hope this helps.

ETA:  I realized that I didn't answer your final questions.  As I said, you would enter fresh activities into Activity, and, if you wanted a situation where you only maintain the most current records for a given user you simply delete all activities for user_id where activity_date is not the most recent date.  It's tough to give sample code because I'm not sure what you mean exactly.  I hope that I at least conveyed the basics properly.

Comment: Well the main issue was with updating the data for each day. For example, if each day had its own activity table, then I could just drop the entire table and recreate it with the new data, but I wasn't sure if this was poor practice, and would create a large amount of tables (1 table for each day for each user).

Comment: Also, in your solution, would you create a separate activity table for each user? Example: User 332 would read/write to table: activity_332 ? Or just 1 giant activity table for every user? (I think that one table would get way too big, which could slow down queries right?)

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding your problem correctly.  I don't see the need for each day to have it's own table unless you are really planning on drawing a hard line in regards to people updating every day.  What if a user misses a day or two?  Do you want them to come back to a completely blank screen?  It would seem to make more sense to just store their last day's activities until they updated again.  In that scenario once user_332 logs in to record his first activity of December 13, you simple delete all records for user_332 where activity_date does not equal December 13.

Comment: Creating a new table for each user seems way over the top.  Unless, of course, you are planning on having a facebook-sized user base.  One activity table should be fine.  You can have literally millions of records in a table before you take a performance hit that a user would even begin to notice.  Even then, you would run into other problem first.  Handling a large number of concurrent users will hurt your performance much more, and long before, a large table in a database ever would.

Comment: Well the original issue was with the way I was storing my data, I didn't know how to go about writing the code to update a table row that the user changed, because I didn't associate any unique key from the database with the data that got loaded into the html table. So if they loaded data from 11/11/2011, and changed row 1, I needed to update that row in the database but I was searching for the row with the activity name/location but that led to problems since there could be duplicate activities/locations in each table...

Comment: But then I realized that I could probably just delete every record that matched the date of the table that they loaded, and insert the entire table's data afterward when they hit save, rather than trying to update individual rows that got changed. I'm also not just storing a single day activity, I'm letting users store activities for as many days as they want and pull them up on a calendar. As far as table size goes, millions of records in a single table is considered OK? I wasn't sure. I thought that having say 10,000 users, each with 50 activities would be overkill.

Comment: 50,000 rows in a table is nothing for most database engines.  I know that MySql touts their ability to handle millions of rows in a table with ease.  There are even a few users who have tables with rows that have literally billions of records.  Just be sure to set up proper maintenance so that you are getting rid of abandoned data in a timely fashion.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure how well it handled large amounts of data like that.  I will set up my database as you outlined. Thanks!